# Protractor is adding \3 to elements ID

Tags: selenium-webdriver, salesforce, protractor

I have an automation that is running on salesforce.
After some changes to the chrome and selenium driver changes any element ID that is starting with a number is getting '\3' at the start of the ID.
Tried to downgrade to older drivers version and it's not doing any change. Tried different chrome version, also without help.

Just to make it clear, I'm trying to search an element by id (it's searching by css of id which I also don't understand why), and its searching by that ID with '\3'

Thanks!

[1 Code where i im finding the element ID and then finding him](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4k3w.png)

[2 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hKKH.png)

Comment: Can you provide the html with a failing id and an example showing how you locate the element?

Comment: Does this happen only for a specific element or for all the "by id" searches?

Comment: Check other methods also for example search by class to see if is related to this method or not or if is specific for starting with certain number/char. Also please be more specific, add the code and the error.

Comment: I provided two pictures that i hope will help. It happen for what I've seen to elements starting with numbers (I tested 1 and 0). Manually instead of the val I sent the ID with 'C' at the start and then it didn't added the '\3'.